# Webpack - The ID of each module in production build

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

When I try to read a Webpack production build, I see something like this

```
(() => {
    var e = {
            8: e => {
                function t(n) {
                    return "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? (e.exports = t = function(e) {
                        return typeof e
                    }, e.exports.default = e.exports, e.exports.__esModule = !0) : (e.exports = t = function(e) {
                        return e && "function" == typeof Symbol && e.constructor === Symbol && e !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof e
                    }, e.exports.default = e.exports, e.exports.__esModule = !0), t(n)
                }
                e.exports = t, e.exports.default = e.exports, e.exports.__esModule = !0
            },
            576: (e, t, n) => {
                var r = e.exports = {
                    content: {
```

Do you know what is the number `8` and `576`? Where they come from and how to get that number using hook?

Thank you so much